# Creating SVN Branch on Local Repository

Tags: svn, version-control

I am trying to create an svn branch on a local repository on my computer.  Based on my understanding of what I read in the [svn book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/), I am supposed to first create the branch directory (using svn mkdir), then copy from my repository into my working copy's branch directory (is this correct?).

Here are the locations for my repository and working directory:

> My local repository: "SVN/repo".
>   My working copy: "SVN_WORK_COPY/repo/trunk"
>   My branch destination: "SVN_WORK_COPY/repo/branches/my_code_branch"

When I typed:

```
    svn copy SVN/repo SVN_WORK_COPY/repo/branches/my_code_branch -m "Created first branch"
```

I got the following message:

> svn: Local, non-commit operations do not take a log message or
>   revision properties

When I typed:

```
svn copy SVN/repo SVN_WORK_COPY/repo/branches/my_code_branch
```

I got the following message:

> svn: 'SVN\repo' is not a working copy

When I typed:

```
svn copy SVN_WORK_COPY/repo/trunk SVN_WORK_COPY/repo/branches/my_code_branch -m "First Branch"
```

I got this message again:

> svn: Local, non-commit operations do not take a log message or
>   revision properties

Finally, When I typed:

```
svn copy SVN_WORK_COPY/repo/trunk SVN_WORK_COPY/repo/branches/my_code_branch
```

I got:

> A      SVN_WORK_COPY/repo/branches/my_code_branch\trunk

and my file (code.txt) is inside this trunk directory. However, I doubt very much that I created a branch correctly because

1. I was not allowed to create a message (using -m)
2. I did not want the "trunk" directory in "my_code_branch" directory
3. I did not see the message "Committed revision 4" (Im at revision 4
   currently)

So where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that's not how you create a branch. You first make a copy of the trunk in the SVN repo (the branch is this copy):

```
svn copy http://the.url/theProject/trunk http://the.url/theProject/branches/my_new_branch -m "created new branch"
```

Then either you switch your current working copy to this new branch (but you should rename the directory to something other than trunk, because it's confusing) or, if you want to have the trunk and the branch locally, you checkout the branch to another location.

Comment: For a local repository on my computer, do I use the "http" as you suggested?

Comment: You use the same protocol as for all the other commands. It could be `file://`, or `http://` or `https://` or `svn://`. It all depends on how you installed SVN. If you don't have any SVN server, then it's `file://`.

Comment: I keep getting error message "svn: Source and dest appear not to be in the same repository (src: 'file:///svn/repo'; dst 'file://SVN_WORK_COPY/repo/branches/my_code_branch')" after typing this: svn copy file:///svn/repo file:///SVN_WORK_COPY/repo/branches/my_code_branch -m "My first branch". I also tried "file://" as you suggested but i got the same error.

Comment: Re-read my answer. Both URLs are URLs in the repository. The first one is the URL of the trunk in the repo. And the second one is the URL of the branch in the repo.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help JB Nizet! It worked: svn copy file:///svn/repo/trunk file:///svn/repo/branches/my_code_branch -m "First Branch" . I got the message "Committed Revision 5"

Comment: So, can't I create a brunch from a non-trunk directory? E.g. here under «trunk» being stored a bunch of different projects *(related in some way though, but different)*, and I need to branch just one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
svn copy -m "creating" http://10.4.55.7/svn/repos/myproject/trunk http://10.4.55.7/svn/repos/myproject/branch/sss
```

Note that `-m "creating"` can be placed at the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

Use this command, the message should be in single quotes.

```
svn copy https://example.com/svn/repo/trunk https://example.com/svn/repo/branches/new_branch -m 'creating new branch'
```